# Approximating a sine function with tflearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am attempting a ridiculously simplistic approximation of a sine function using tflearn, inspired by [this](http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html) paper.

```
import tflearn 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# generate cosine function
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,10000)
y = np.sin(x)



# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[10,10000])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1000)
net = tflearn.layers.core.activation (net, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.regression(net)


# Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(x, y,batch_size=10)
```

But I keep running into a

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10,) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 10, 10000)'

error.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you switch 10 and 10000 on the first line of network building?

Comment: Exactly the same error I'm afraid

Comment: change `np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,10000)` to `np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,10000).reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! changing the line `net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None,1])` got rid of the errors

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I was not assigning a shape to the `x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,10000)` tensor:

Solved (@lejlot) by changing the line to `np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,10000).reshape(-1, 1)`

In the line `input_data(shape=[10,10000])` the shape of each input tensor is actually [None,1] and so changing this line to net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None,1]) solved the issue in the end.